# Search git for a code pattern using git grep

Tags: regex, bash, git, grep

I've been trying to find instances of the t() function in source code on the dev branch using git. Came up with the following line

```
git branch -a | tr -d \* | sed '/->/d' | xargs git grep -E -e "/(t\(\').*\'\)/sU"
```

Here the search is done on all branches, but still I get no results from the query. Simple search queries ( git grep "t('" ) work perfectly fine, but is not usable for this purpose. 
ExtendedRexp is enabled from git config.

Anybody had similar issues?

Comment: why `xargs git grep`, shouldn't it be just  `xargs grep `?

Comment: `git grep` is used to search for tracked files in the GitHub repository.

Comment: The syntax of the regular expression `/…/sU` is strange, it seems you confuse `grep` and `sed`. What exactly you're trying to search? What the "flags" `sU` are supposed to do?

Comment: `U` is a PHP/PCRE modifier that switches greediness. `grep`  with POSIX ERE does not support lazy/possessive quantifiers, it only supprots greedy ones. `s` is a modifier that does not work with `grep` since `grep` works on  a per line basis, and `s` modifier makes a `.` in a PCRE regex match line break chars that it does not match by default.

Comment: Are you looking for commits where calls to the function were added, change, or deleted historically or instances in the head of each branch?

Comment: Well, `git` is neither `perl` nor `php` so it doesn't support the syntax, and certainly not with option `-E`. For PCRE one must use `-P`.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the commits where the function calls were added and changed. I was not sure about the syntax, so probably, the modifiers were probably incorrect. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Escaping the single quotes in the regular expression should not be necessary. Also, to avoid matching other functions that end with a 't', such as `get`, you can use `\W` which will match any non non-word character.

```
git branch -a | tr -d \* | sed '/->/d' | xargs git grep -E -e "\Wt\('.*'\)"
```

If you want to capture a group within the matching result, then you can add additional parentheses. For example:

[image: Rubular example]

Comment: Yes that is definitely a better regex for finding the t function!. 
Still no results from the git grep though :/

Comment: If you are still not seeing results, then I would recommend making the regex less restrictive. Note that this will currently only match if the arguments to `t` are passed as literals with single quotes. You can see this in my example test strings.

Comment: Regex works as expected while running on example strings.
I think the problem is with the usage of git grep.

Comment: I verified that it worked with git grep by putting a t in one of my git checkouts. It could be a git configuration issue.